# How to set root folder for grunt-express?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I need to set my web root folder one directory up from where my static files are located.  Its a long story as to why this is needed !

Here is a snipped of my grunt js file

```
// The actual grunt server settings
    express: {
        all : {
            options : {
                hostname: 'localhost',
                port:9000,
                bases: ('../DirectoryAbove')
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using an absolute path instead?

```
express: {
    all : {
        options : {
            hostname: 'localhost',
            port:9000,
            bases: path.resolve(__dirname, '../DirectoryAbove')
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bases option is an array of strings. Use that instead.

Comment: Ive tried that makes no difference. Just can't seem to get the server to use the directory above as the root for the server